# Shiv'a Asar Ushlosh Meyot - mi yodeya?

Tags: number, mi-yodeya-series

### Who knows three hundred seventeen?

### ?שבעה עשר ושלוש מאות - מי יודע

In the spirit of the song ["Echad - mi yodeya"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Echad_Mi_Yodea), please post interesting and significant Jewish facts about the number 317.

Check out [mi-yodeya-series](/questions/tagged/mi-yodeya-series) for the previous three hundred sixteen entries in this ongoing series.

Please include sources for your information wherever possible, as with all other answers on this site.

Comment: יאוש = 317 so I give up

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The average lifespan of the ten men in the line of descent from (and including) [Sheim](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shem) to [Avraham Avinu](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abraham) was a little more than 317 years:

Sheim   - 600
Arpachshad -    438
Shelach - 433
Eiver   - 464
Peleg   - 239
Re'u    - 239
Serug - 230
Nachor  - 148
Terach  - 205
Avraham - 175

(See [Bereishit 11:10 - 32](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/8175#v=10) and [Bereishit 25:7](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/8220#v=7). Statistic first observed by [Dr. Gabriel Cousens](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gabriel_Cousens) in *[Spiritual Nutrition](http://books.google.com/books?id=1dUoCp2C6egC)*, p.[248](http://books.google.com/books?id=1dUoCp2C6egC&pg=PA248&lpg=PA248&source=bl&ots=nA8hoCYXhM&sig=0lnPKIm8fx03QNBC7e66XuezG70&hl=en&sa=X&ei=kYsLUqrCHMH42AWUvYGAAg&ved=0CDgQ6AEwAQ#v=onepage&q&f=false).)

Answer (score 4):

Per [Wikpedia](http://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%96%D7%99%D7%94%D7%95%D7%99_%D7%9E%D7%A7%D7%95%D7%9D_%D7%94%D7%9E%D7%A7%D7%93%D7%A9) the length of the northern wall of the Har HaBayis is 317 meters:

> ארכו של הכותל הצפוני כ-317 מטר

Answer (score 2):

**317**- the number of times in the Talmud Bavli where the answer to a question is unknown and  "**תיקו**"
--understood to mean the question shall remain unresolved-- (**lit**: "let it stand") is invoked.

- See [this sefer](https://tablet.otzar.org/he/book/book.php?book=62143&width=0&scroll=0&udid=0&pagenum=1) by R' Aaron Pessin where he lists and discusses each of these 317 cases.